# Please tell me what is wrong with saying "explain about"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

I recently had to translate an official interview for a respected magazine in my country, and I wrote the following:

> "John Smith, the founder and CEO of the project **explains about** the future strategy, investors, and, of course, development of the industry."

I am not an ultra-good at translating business English, but I was told that my text, and this sentence, in particular, had some unacceptable mistakes. The mistake appears to be "explain about." I mean?.. I quickly googled, and it turns out a ton of people use the expression this way.
Moreover, I was told that this is completely wrong, and not a debatable issue, like "we is" level wrong.

So, please tell me what is wrong. The one thing I managed to find is that the word "explain" already implies the "about part," but I wouldn't attribute that to a grave mistake.

Sorry for the long rant, waiting for your explanations!

Comment: *Explaining a strategy* means describing details about the strategy. Adding *about* might be - in descending order of likelihood - (1) awkwardly superfluous, not just redundant; (2) using 'about' to mean 'around' - i.e. avoiding a discussion of the strategy itself by talking about related issues; or (3) holding a meta-discussion of the strategy.

Comment: @Lawrence Well explained about.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am tempted to change the question title to "Please explain about what is wrong with 'explain about'."  :-)

Comment: [We is not gonna explain about what's incorrect in this sentence.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+is+not+gonna%22) Or say (or talk about) which *specific* aspect is ***most*** incorrect.

Comment: *Please explain **the <something>** about <something else>.*

Comment: I second what @Lawrence said: "explain about the strategy" is conversational, and short for "explain [something] about the strategy", especially when you don't know what that something is. It's referring to meta information about the strategy, not the actual strategy itself. And either way, it doesn't sound right in a professional context. I confirmed this in google--lots of examples on informal sites/youtube, but virtually no examples in books/ngrams.

Comment: I know this won't be terribly helpful, hence the comment vs. answer, but "explain about" is just not idiomatic.  To hear it or read it is the equivalent of hearing nails being scratched on a chalkboard.

Comment: @KristinaL - I agree; we can _**talk** about something, **laugh** about something, **gripe** about something_, but we don’t “explain about something” – we simply _explain something._